# Spring - Add security on Generic CRUD Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, generics

I'm making a generic controller with CRUD operations(like this https://gist.github.com/wvuong/5673644) and I'm looking for an approach to include the security on those endpoints.

As all my controller implementations also have generic authorities(ex. CATEGORY_LIST, PROJECT_LIST, LOCATION_LIST) Is there a way to include this on the generic controller using the @PreAuthorize annotation or any other aproach.

This project is almost done, so I cannot use a fully new rest implementation and I'm trying to clean some code because our controllers have methods that only call the super implementation like this:

```
@Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CATEGORY_ADD')")
    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@Valid @RequestBody  Category m,BindingResult bindingResult) throws CustomValidateException {
        return super.create(m,bindingResult);
    }
```

Just for the @PreAuthorize annotation and trying to avoid that kind of methods. I remember that I saw one post here about that but could find it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is what is known as Aspect Orientated Programming - AOP, and you can use the AspectJ implementation of this which is integrated into Spring. AOP is whereby you take an aspect, such as security out of your code and you put it into an Aspect. That helps prevent having duplicate code all over the place, and you simply have interceptors which trigger the security checks when you want.

If you don't want to introduce an AOP framework like AspectJ, you could also instead put the security in a different spot, like in your super type, and have some sort of bean which is injected into a field in your abstract super type which performs the security for you. As along as all sub-types will also be Spring Beans this will work.

```
@Component
public class SecurityBean {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CATEGORY_ADD')")
    public void doSecurityChecks(Category m) {
        // any other custom security logic you want
    }
}

public abstract class ControllerSuperType {

    @Autowired
    SecurityBean securityBean;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@Valid @RequestBody  Category m, BindingResult bindingResult) throws CustomValidateException {
        // other stuff already in your super type
        securityBean.doSecurityChecks(m);
    }

}
```